# Inconsistent results when using Round in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle function. Due to privacy issues, I can't include the whole function, but the relevant line is :-

```
WHEN in_tariff_length = 36 THEN round( ( ( (in_agreed / 100) * 80) * in_uplift) / 100,2) * 3
```

..which is rounded to 2 decimal places, and returns 1655.58

When I use

```
WHEN in_tariff_length = 36 THEN round( ( ( (in_agreed / 100) * 80) * in_uplift) / 100,3) * 3
```

..which is rounded to 3 decimal places, and returns 1655.568

The result I need is 1655.57.

All values sent to and returned from the function are NUMBER.

Comment: I'm sure this is consistent.  The rules for rounding are just more arcane than you think.

Comment: Is it possible to have 1655.57 returned, on the logic that to 2 decimal places this is the closest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't round something, multiply by 3 and get 1655.57

```
551.86 * 3 = 1655.58
551.856 * 3 = 1655.568
1655.57 / 3 = 551.856666667
```

I suggest multiply first, then round.

Comment: Very good point, and I hadn't looked at the issue from that angle. Thank you for steering me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Please look closely at the second function

```
round( ( ( (in_agreed / 100) * 80) * in_uplift) / 100,3)
```

`Round( something, 3)` means round to **3 decimal places** but not to 2

Comment: Apologies - I've edited the question, but the issue is still the same - I need the result to the closest 2 decimal places. So 1655.568 should become 1655.57.